# Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix of rank $r$. If $U = \{X \in M_{nn}: AX=0\}$, find dim($U$)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am completely puzzled. The solution is $n(n-r)$, but I have no idea how to start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ has $n$ columns, each one of which may independently be any vector in the nullspace of $A$. $A$ has nullity $n-r$, so the answer is $n(n-r)$.